# Using barrier to wait for integration flow to complete

Tags: spring, spring-integration

I have an integration flow where some of the steps are async and some of sync. I want to use the `barrier` to block the `Main` thread until all async tasks have completed. Based on the documentation, there are two ways to use the barrier.

1. Send a second trigger message to the input channel of the barrier.
2. Invoke the trigger method manually of the barrier

In my use case a message comes in the flow and then goes through several components until it reaches the `completed` channel. I want the main thread to be blocked until the original messages reaches the completed channel. So it seems appropriate to use the option #2 and invoke the barrier trigger method after reaching the `completed` state. This doesnt seem to work. Here is a simplified version of my flow.

```
<int:gateway
    service-interface="...BarrierGateway"
    id="barrierGateway" default-request-channel="input">
</int:gateway>

<int:channel id="input">
    <int:dispatcher task-executor="executor" />
</int:channel>

<int:service-activator input-channel="input" output-channel="completed">
    <bean class="...BarrierSA" />
</int:service-activator>

<int:channel id="completed" />
<int:service-activator input-channel="completed"
    ref="barrier1.handler" method="trigger" />

<int:barrier id="barrier1" input-channel="input" timeout="10000" />
```

I am sending a message to the `gateway` which passes it to the `input` channel which is using a `dispatcher` so a new thread is started to pass the message forward. At this point, I want to block the `main` thread while the `Executor-1` thread goes through the flow. The rest of the flow is simple. My `service-activator` sleeps for 3 seconds before returning the message to simulate a delay. Once the message is received in the `completed` channel, the service-activator should invoke the `barrier trigger` method and only at this point, the main thread should be released. Instead, the main thread is released right after the dispatcher starts a new thread. I have tried specifying a constant correlation id ('abc') but that didnt help.

Answer (score 2):

I see you're caught in a trap.

The `<int:barrier>` suspends the Thread just on the message message, but only that Thread which brings that message to him. Looking to your config it is the same `input` channel with `Executor`. The purpose of the `ExecutorChannel` to shift message to a different thread, but not suspend the caller's thread.

From other side you have one more mistake around that `input`. You declare two subscribers for him, where only one of them will be called by the `round-robin` balancing strategy.

To fix your task we should have one more top-level channel as `<publish-subscribe-channel>`. And right, already now you can have two subscribers.

One of them should be a `<bridge>` to your `input` `ExecutorChannel`. And another the desired `<barrier>`. And only now it can suspend (block in your terms) the main thread from the `<gateway>`.

From other side the more simpler solution would be don't use the `<barrier>` at all. The `<gateway>` has an ability to to block the caller's thread and wait for reply. Of course, that works when the gateway methods isn't `void`.

And one more point to your config: if you don't wait for reply in the gateway, the `<barrier>` will fail with the

```
throw new DestinationResolutionException("no output-channel or replyChannel header available");
```

So, consider to use something as an `output-channel` there  a well.

Comment: The barrier is for more sophisticated environments; for a simple use case like this, as @Artem says, the main thread will be suspended in the gateway (if there is a return type from the method) until the flow ends (regardless of any async handoffs) or until the `reply-timeout` is exceeded - which is infinity by default. If you have a void return then the barrier is the right solution, but each side of the barrier has to run on a separate thread, as Artem says.